# JavaScript: Displaying Interactive Maps with Dynamic Data

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to use Google Maps API to display interactive maps with dynamic data. However, I can't figure out how to set it up in my code.

In my website, I have list of cards, and I want to make it so that when a particular element inside each card is clicked, an interactive map will be displayed based on the location data attached to the card.

My code looks like this:

**List of Cards**

HTML

```
<div class="list-group ${type}-item" id="${result.rows[x].id}" onclick="propertyClicked(window.event, ${result.rows[x].id});">
  <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <h5 class="mb-1">${result.rows[x].reporterName}</h5>
      <small>${moment(new Date(parseInt(result.rows[x].datetime)).toDatetimeLocal('unformatted').toString(), 'YYYYMMDDhhmmss').fromNow()}</small>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-1">Bedrooms: ${result.rows[x].bedrooms}</p>
    <p class="mb-1">Furniture Types: ${result.rows[x].furnitureTypes === '' ? 'None' : result.rows[x].furnitureTypes}</p>
    <p class="mb-1">Location: ${result.rows[x].propertyLocation === '' ? 'No Location' : result.rows[x].propertyLocation}</p>
    <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
      <p class="mb-1">Monthly Rent Price: $${parseFloat(result.rows[x].monthlyRentPrice)}</p>
      <div>
        <ion-icon name="pin" class="mr-4 purple note-icon" id="note-location" onclick="onLocationClicked('${result.rows[x].propertyLocation}');"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="create" class="mr-4 purple note-icon" id="edit-note" onclick="onEditClicked(${result.rows[x].id});"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="trash" class="note-icon purple" id="delete-note" onclick="onDeleteClicked(${result.rows[x].id}, '${type}');"></ion-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Inside the HTML above, I have an onclick listener on the location icon and this is the function:

JS

```
onLocationClicked = address => {
    let lat, lng;
    axios.post(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${address}&key=${API_KEY}`).then(response => {
        lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        document.getElementsByClassName('modal-title')[0].textContent = 'Location';
        document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].insertAdjacentHTML(
            'beforeend',
            `<div id='map' style='height:100%'></div>`
        );
        toggleElDisplay('delete-note-btn', 'id');
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat, lng},
            zoom: 8
        });
        document.getElementById('modal-close').textContent = 'Close';
        toggleElDisplay('modal-close', 'id', null, true);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        document.getElementById('modal-close').addEventListener('click', () => {
            document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].innerHTML = '';
        });
    }).catch(error => console.error(error));
};
```

My problem is that, due to the way Google Maps API works, it requires an `initMap` function or an initializer that needs to be globally defined. However, in my code, that kind of setup won't work for me because there will be no way to populate an address into the map since there is none available until the location icon is clicked.

I don't know if I was able to explain well but I hope my question is not confusing.

Please, how can I approach or solve this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you fill in the api key?

Comment: yeah, I hid that from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue, by creating the `initMap` function globally, and setting the map with a dummy location data.

Then when the location icon is clicked, i changed the location data of the map to the appropriate one and then display the map.

So my JS now looks like this:

```js
initMap = () => {
    let myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
    let mapOptions = { zoom: 10, center: myLatlng };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('rough-map'), mapOptions);
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        title: "Random Location"
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    toggleElDisplay('rough-map', 'id');
};

onLocationClicked = address => {
    let lat, lng;
    axios.post(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${address}&key=${API_KEY}`).then(response => {
        lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        document.getElementsByClassName('modal-title')[0].textContent = 'Location';
        document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].insertAdjacentHTML(
            'beforeend',
            `<div id='map' style='min-height: 300px; max-height: 600px;'></div>`
        );
        toggleElDisplay('delete-note-btn', 'id');
        let myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        let mapOptions = { zoom: 15, center: myLatlng };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatlng, title: address });
        marker.setMap(map);
        document.getElementById('modal-close').textContent = 'Close';
        toggleElDisplay('modal-close', 'id', null, true);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        document.getElementById('modal-close').addEventListener('click', () => {
            document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].innerHTML = '';
        });
    }).catch(error => console.error(error));
};
```